# What is the difference between passing component to declarations or to directives?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's say I have usual component `MyComponent`. To use it, should I pass it to `declarations` array in my main module or `directives` array in main component?

```
// 1)
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

// 2)
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  directives: [MyComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

What if the component is deep into application tree, could I use it anywhere in main module, if passed to `declarations` array?

angular@2.0.0-rc.5

Comment: If the component is deep into application tree you can split your code into featured modules that have private scope for their declarations and then import these modules into main module https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules

Comment: @yurzui Yes, I plan to do that, but one thing is bothering me. How to create shared services? Because if I pass them into `providers` array in my main module they won't be available to my child modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`directives` and `pipes` in `@Component()` and `@Directive()` are deprecated. `declarations` is the new RC.5/`NgModule`s way.